# Open Cv image Stitching

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi I am new Opencv and english. I do stitching two image and result image is : 
[image]

But I want to delete destroy line .  How can do it  ? .

Comment: but it looks like both images have different contrast and brightness are you talking about trying to equalise both sides here?

Comment: Thanks for answer but I traying equalization but not working

Comment: Well you have to take the average brightness from both sides, get the difference and then apply the difference to the other side would be one approach

Comment: try the code [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/90288/copy-histogram-of-an-image-to-another/) to equalize both image

Answer (score 0):

You need to blend the images in order to remove this line.

You can implement one of the techniques that is mentioned in this [PDF](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2010_spring/Lectures/blending.pdf). Personally I recommend technique described in [this paper](http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/thevenaz0701.pdf) on page 138. You can use also technique described in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html) OpenCV tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using opencv, have a look at the [stitching_detailed](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp) example. It gives you ability to pick the module to be used at every stage of stitching based on your image. Two things that will help the image you have shown are exposure compensation and blending.

I would suggest choosing GAIN or GAIN_BLOCKS for exposure compensation and MULTI_BAND for blending.